# Loader not shown when javascript is running but is shown when debugging

Tags: jquery

My CSS:

```
.loader1 {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(../Content/images/ezgif-1527767856.gif);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
}
```

My javascript:

```
function filterme() {
    $("#loader1").show();

    // in between I have a lot of code that takes time to run.
    $("#loader1").hide();
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="loader1" id="loader1" style="display:none"></div>  
<button type="button" onclick="filterme()">Click ME</button>
```

Clicking the button runs the javascript fine but the loader is not shown.

When I use a debugger and check it the loader is shown. How do I make it visible in non debugging mode?

Comment: loader1 is a class name right? then you need to use `$('.loader')` instead of `("#loader1")` . "#" is used for `id`

Comment: I made a jsfiddle out of your code and modified it a little, this works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/9Lbojrfm/1/

Comment: What debugger are you using? Do you mean it works when your browser's console is open or when some web development extension is running?

Comment: Thanks Simon your logic kind makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like this is a threading problem. The browser is so busy running your CPU-intensive, long-running code that it doesn't quite get around to updating what's visible on the page before it's time to hide it again anyway.

So, perhaps this:

```
function filterme() {
    $("#loader1").show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        //in between i have a huge code that takes time to run
        $("#loader1").hide();
    }, 10);
}
```

That is, introduce a tiny delay between showing `#loader1` and then executing the code. This gives the browser a moment to handle the UI update before diving in headfirst to the intensive stuff.

As an aisde, don't use `onclick=` to create event handlers. In your JavaScript, do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click( filterme );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite late, but if anyone has the same issue, you can use Ajax with async: false and have the loader shown:

```js
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function () {
        $(".loader").css("display", "table");
    },
    success: function (data) {
    },
});
```

Just set the call function of the loader in the `beforeSend` event.

Answer (score -1):

Put your function outside document.ready function.

Comment: Please explain how that would help.